# Parsing HTML of Youtube playlists

Tags: python, scripting, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble parsing the HTML of youtube Playlists. For example, when I inspect the  tags of "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_". I see the class name "**yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-playlist-video-renderer**" . But this does not work when I select the elements using bs4. However, I found another piece of working code online which selects the following class "**pl-video-title-link**" . But I am not able to find this class on the web page and none of the  tags have this class? Attached is the working code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/playlist? 
list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_')
page = r.text
soup = bs(page,'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all('a',{'class':'pl-video-title-link'})
for l in res:
print (l.get("href"))
```

Comment: Almost certainly you should use something like Chromedriver and Selenium for this--the element with your desired class is probably created dynamically with JS.

Answer (score 1):

This page changes its structure with JavaScript, but you can print the soup upon downloading and see, where the video links are initially. In this case, in tag `<tr>` with class `pl-video`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

for i, tr in enumerate(soup.select('tr.pl-video')):
    print('{}. {}'.format(i + 1, tr['data-title']))
    print('https://www.youtube.com' + tr.a['href'])
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
1. Shell Scripting Tutorial for Beginners 1 -  Introduction
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQepf9fY6cE&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_&index=2&t=0s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Shell Scripting Tutorial for Beginners 2 - using Variables and Comments
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQv4W-JfrmQ&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_&index=3&t=0s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Shell Scripting Tutorial for Beginners 3 - Read User Input
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AcSkkNAsGCY&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_&index=4&t=0s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... all the way to:

32. How Install VirtualBox Guest Additions on Ubuntu 18.04 Guest / virtual machine
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNecdUsuTPw&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_&index=33&t=0s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
33. How to install Java JDK 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Debian Linux)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RJ60fqeTN4&list=PLS1QulWo1RIYmaxcEqw5JhK3b-6rgdWO_&index=34&t=0s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```